# How to access variable outside of websocket function

Tags: python, websocket

I'm generating a signal in the websocket.on_message() function and I need to access it's state outside of the function. I try it like this but it doesn't work. Why is it not working and how can make it work?

```
import execution_long_MKR
import execution_short_MKR

#...code..

def on_message(ws, message):

    #...code...

    global longsig
    global shortsig
    longsig = False
    shortsig = False

    if df['signal'][lastrow] == "long": 
        longsig = True
               
    if df['signal'][lastrow] == "short": 
        shortsig = True                    

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()


def execute():

    while True:

        if longsig:
            execution_long_MKR.main()
        
        if shortsig:
            execution_short_MKR.main()    
    
x = threading.Thread(target=execute)
x.start()
```

I also tried to declare the variables as `on_message.longsig`

Comment: Your code never runs ``execute`` – it doesn't even *define* it. Start it (in a thread) before telling ws to ``run_forever``.

Comment: I tried to start the thread before on_message() function, but then also nothing happens. Inside of on_message it's not possible because a new thread will be created with each websocket update

Comment: Sorry i have to correct my comment: I tried to start the thread before on_message() function, but then I get an error that `longsig` is not defined. Also when I try `on_message.longsig`.

Comment: Just define both ``...sig = False`` in the global scope before running either function.